# Can’t inverse encoded categorical variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a categorical variable (A,B,C) in my data frame. Then, I encoded it (made it numerical) in order to pass into a neural network.

However, my final visualization graph shows me the encoded values for the categorical variables and I am having difficulties mapping it back to its original values.

I used this command to encode my categorical variables (data type=object) into numerical values first:

```
encoders = {}
for x in df.columns:
    if df[x].dtypes=='object':
      le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
      df[x]=le.fit_transform(df[x].astype(str))
      encoders[x] = le     

corr = df.corr()
```

Then, I am decoding those using this code (right before the final visualization):

```
for x, le in encoders.items():
    df[x] = le.inverse_transform(df[x])

    # Visualization: plotting categorical variables (A,B,C) in scatterplot using Seaborn.
    sns.lmplot(x="A", y="B", data=df, fit_reg=False, hue='C',legend=False)
    display()
```

...but the visualization STILL shows the encoded values instead of the categorical ones (see screenshot below). No mapping was done. Why?

[image]

Comment: Why don't you do df[x+"_encoded"]=le.fit_transform(df[x].astype(str)), do whatever you need to do with the encoded value, and then get the original labels from df[x] when plotting?

Answer (score 1):

You have to store the original `LabelEncoder`. The mapping is storing within that class. So something along the lines of

```
encoders = {}
for x in df.columns:
    if df[x].dtypes=='object':
       le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
       df[x]=le.fit_transform(df[x].astype(str))
       encoders[x] = le

for x, le in encoders.items():
    df[x] = le.inverse_transform(df[x])
```

Or even better, don't overwrite your labels with the encoded ones, but create a new column in your dataframe.

Comment: Once encoded doesn't the type of the column change? So does it make sense to still check if column is of type `object`

Comment: @SruthiV I tried both codes (yours and users26...). None of them worked. Could it be the placement of the Decoding code? I updated my code sample above. Please advise.

Comment: @user2653663 I tried your code but it did not work for me. May it be the placement? I edited my original post and attached also the visuals. Please advise.